# How do I select a class but not its inside element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

Say I have

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="myclass">
       <span class="otherclass"></span>
       and many other classes...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to capture the click event on .mydiv but not inside .myclass.

I tried `.mydiv:not(.myclass)` but it doesn't seem to work. I think it's because I might be clicking on the otherclass so the `:not(.myclass)` is not working.  How can I get the area I want to get? Thanks!

Comment: `#mydiv :not(.myclass)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `#mydiv` clickable, do whatever you wish, and stop event propagation from `.myclass`, so the event will not bubbleup from myclass to mydiv

```
     $('#mydiv').click(function(){
        // do anything
     })

    // stop event propagation
     $('.myclass').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        })
```

Comment: cool.. But I might still want to capture some click events inside .myclass. Would it affect that?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on `mydiv` id and write your code in that function and on `.myclass` click event you simply write `return false` to stop further execution of function.

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    // stuff your code here
});

//Use `return false` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`
$('.myclass').click(function(e){
  return false;
})
```

> e.stopPropagation() is dangerous please read **[Documentation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)**

Answer (score 0):

Calling **[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** will remove an event handler

```
    $("#mydiv").on('click', function () {
        alert("You clicked mydiv");
    });

    $(".myclass").off('click', function () {
    });
           or like this

   $(".myclass").off();
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t0u007uq/1/)**